# ASP Query return

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have this ASP page.  I am trying show the results of the metalquery, listing all order numbers.  When I do this now, it just shows the first order number.  Is there a way to show all order numbers from the query?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.Odbc" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<!-- webkit5 includes --!>
<!-- <meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" /> --!>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta content="minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=0.6667, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" />
<script src="javascript/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Open Inkjet Orders</title>
<meta content="keyword1,keyword2,keyword3" name="keywords" />
<meta content="Description of your page" name="description" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="topbar" class="transparent">
    <div id="leftnav">
        <a href="Home.aspx">
            <img alt="home" src="images/home.png">
        </a>
        <a href="OpenOrders.aspx">Open Orders</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
<%
OdbcConnection cn;
OdbcCommand cmd;

String canvasQuery = "select count(distinct(info.orderid)) from orderinfo info, orderiteminfo item where info.orderstatus = 'Open' and info.orderid = item.orderid and item.deptcode in (35) and info.duedate = DATE(NOW())";
String wallWrapQuery = "select count(distinct(info.orderid)) from orderinfo info, orderiteminfo item where info.orderstatus = 'Open' and info.orderid = item.orderid and item.deptcode in (41) and info.duedate = DATE(NOW())";
String fineartQuery = "select count(distinct(info.orderid)) from orderinfo info, orderiteminfo item where info.orderstatus = 'Open' and info.orderid = item.orderid and item.deptcode in (03) and info.duedate = DATE(NOW())";
String metalQuery = "select distinct(info.orderid) from orderinfo info, orderiteminfo item where info.orderstatus = 'Open' and info.orderid = item.orderid and item.deptcode in (48) and info.duedate = DATE(NOW())";

int canvasOpen, wallWrapOpen, fineartOpen, metalOpen;


cn= new OdbcConnection("dsn=xxxx;UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxx");

cmd=new OdbcCommand(canvasQuery,cn);
cn.Open();
OdbcDataReader DbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

DbReader.Read();
canvasOpen = DbReader.GetInt32(0);

cmd=new OdbcCommand(wallWrapQuery,cn);
DbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DbReader.Read();
wallWrapOpen = DbReader.GetInt32(0);

cmd=new OdbcCommand(fineartQuery,cn);
DbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DbReader.Read();
fineartOpen = DbReader.GetInt32(0);

cmd=new OdbcCommand(metalQuery,cn);
DbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DbReader.Read();
metalOpen = DbReader.GetInt32(0);

DbReader.Close();
cn.Close();

%>
    <span class="graytitle">Due Inkjet Orders</span>
        <ul class="pageitem">
            <li class="menu">

                    <span class="name">Canvas Dept: <%=canvasOpen%></span>

            </li>
            <li class="menu">
                <span class="name">Wall Cling Dept: <%=wallWrapOpen%></span>
            </li>
            <li class="menu">
                    <span class="name">Fine Art Dept: <%=fineartOpen%></span>
            </li>
            <li class="menu">
                    <span class="name">Metal Dept: <%=metalOpen%></span>
            </li>
            <li>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You considered looping through the records in dbReader instead of just showing the first one?

Comment: You're only showing 1 value because that's all you're getting from your code. I'd suggest using a repeater or some sort of ASP.NET control that can show the results of your query via databinding.

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep calling the Read() method until it returns false.

Each Read() call only returns a single record.

Try this:

```
while(DbReader.Read())
{
   metalOpen = DbReader.GetInt32(0);

%>
    <span class="graytitle">Due Inkjet Orders</span>
        <ul class="pageitem">
           <li class="menu">
                <span class="name">Canvas Dept: <%=canvasOpen%></span>
            </li>
            <li class="menu">
                <span class="name">Wall Cling Dept: <%=wallWrapOpen%></span>
            </li>
            <li class="menu">
                <span class="name">Fine Art Dept: <%=fineartOpen%></span>
            </li>
            <li class="menu">
                <span class="name">Metal Dept: <%=metalOpen%></span>
            </li>
            <li>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </span>
%>
}
DbReader.Close();
cn.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

The following query, at the beginning of your code block, is specifying a query that may return zero, one or more records - more precisely the `orderid` field:

```
String metalQuery = "select distinct(info.orderid) from orderinfo info, orderiteminfo item where info.orderstatus = 'Open' and info.orderid = item.orderid and item.deptcode in (48) and info.duedate = DATE(NOW())";
```

And this block is executing this query against your source database:

```
cmd=new OdbcCommand(metalQuery,cn);
DbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Now you need to iterate through each result. You may accomplish this by using the `.Read()` method. neat thing is, `.Read()` can be used for as long as there's records on the ResultSet.

You may then encapsulate your `.Read()` iterations on a While block:

```
while(DbReader.Read())
{
    //Here goes your code
}
```

In your case, it would probably look like this:

```
while(DbReader.Read())
{
    metalOpen = DbReader.GetInt32(0);
%>
    <span class="name">Metal Dept: <%=metalOpen%></span>
<%
}
```

Of course, adjust the output as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a loop to read multiple records (and change metalOpen to a `List<int>` to store multiple values:

```
List<int> metalOpen = new List<int>();
cmd=new OdbcCommand(metalQuery,cn);
DbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(DbReader.Read())
{
   metalOpen.Add(DbReader.GetInt32(0));
}
```

Then decide how to diplay them - the simplest way is to show a comma-separated list:

```
        <li class="menu">
                <span class="name">Metal Dept: <%=string.Join(", ",metalOpen)%></span>
        </li>
```